# Windows 10 reinstall

Tags: windows, windows-10, windows-8, license

I have a laptop that came preinstalled with Windows 8 OEM.  I upgraded to Windows 10 when the free upgrade was available.

I want to die a clean install of the OS to remove all of the bloat ware.  My understanding was that you can do this and be legally licensed because of the original OEM license.

Will this still work for me if I install Windows 10 since it originally came installed with Windows 8?

Comment: Please see the previous question that I referenced above.  It should work without any problems.

Comment: Windows 10 installs its own bloatware; it might be more efficient to use Derapifier or alternative to remove the garbage http://alternativeto.net/software/pc-decrapifier/